# Difference between residence permit and common format residence permit

Tags: visas, uk, transit, netherlands

[image]I am an Indian and have Netherlands residence Permit Type 1.
I am travelling from Amsterdam and will be transiting in LHR towards New delhi do I need transit visa?

In the exemptions it says if you have a common format residence permit issued by an European Economic Area then you do not need a transit visa.

Can I consider my Netherlands residence permit as common format residence permit or there is difference between the two?

Below are the flight details:
Flight details
BA431 Amsterdam --> London
BA257 London --> New Delhi

Comment: Can you add a picture of your permit with all personal info blacked out? Some countries only deliver common format permits, others deliver both common format and national formats depending on the specific type of permit. I have no idea of which category the Netherlands are in.

Comment: Thank you! I am attaching the same. With the provided answers I believe that i do not the transit visa.

Comment: Were you able to travel without transit visa ?. I have the exact same situation as you. Your answer will be of great help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [the EU's list of acceptable documents](https://ec.europa.eu/home-affairs/sites/default/files/what-we-do/policies/borders-and-visas/document-security/docs/list-of-residence-permits-issued-by-member-states.pdf), the following documents issued by the Netherlands are uniform-format residence permits:

- Regulier bepaalde tijd (Regular - fixed-term)
- Regulier onbepaalde tijd (Regular - indefinite)
- Asiel bepaalde tijd (Asylum - fixed-term)
- Asiel onbepaalde tijd (Asylum - indefinite)
- EU/EER (Gemeenschapsonderdanen) (EU nationals)

If you have one of those documents, you should be all set. If you have another document, such as a Het Geprivilegeerdendocument (Privileged persons document), Visum voor terugkeer (return visa), or some other document which is in fact not a residence permit at all, you are more likely to experience difficulty.

Comment: A **Regular - fixed term** is a **Type I document** and should be a plastic card (common format residence permit): See image at: [PRADO NLD-HO-08001](https://www.consilium.europa.eu/prado/en/NLD-HO-08001/index.html)

Comment: Thank mlc !! 
Regulier bepaalde tijd. I believe I do not need transit visa in uk.
I hope there is no technicality hidden b/w uniform-format and common format.

Comment: @Priya the picture you've added to the question shows that your card is in the correct format.  Both "uniform format" and "common format" are supposed to indicate that the document complies with the EU's specified format for residence permits.  In this context, they mean the same thing.